# Zip-Library with unicode und 7z support

Tags: library, unicode

For our project (Language C++/C) we are looking for a zip library which support:

- unpacking of archives (creating would be nice, but is not that important)
- Unicode file names (as archive, as content and unpacking into Unicode directories
- normal zip files
- 7z files (LZMA optimal would be LZMA2 support also)
- available on windows (32 AND 64 bits) and linux systems

To be clear, not only the compression algorithm is needed. It also should take care of the whole file handling stuff. Also commercial solution are ok (if reasonable priced)

currently we use [Minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html), which is build on top of zlib
it supports windows and Linux but no unicode and no 7z(LZMA),
The 7zip sdk only works on windows systems. 
[Libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/) doesn't support LZMA/7z.

Comment: why you don't use [p7zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip#Variants)?

Comment: thanks for the tip
it was unknown to us..